# ¿como puedo mostrar datos de un arreglo session php?

Tags: php, array, echo

estoy haciendo el formulario de un cliente de un servicio web en php y quiero mostrar los datos del carrito o de la compra pero no me deja e intentado casting de datos diferentes metodos para mostrar
esto es mi codigo

tengo los datos almacenados en esta funcion:

```
function agregarLicor($almaceno, $idLicor, $cantidad = 1) {
        $_SESSION["carrito"][$idLicor]= array(
            "id" => $almaceno[0],
            "nombre" => $almaceno[1],
            "valor" =>  $almaceno[2],
            "cantidad" => $almaceno[3],
            "descripcion" => $almaceno[4],
            "tipo" => $almaceno[5],
            "foto" => $almaceno[6],
            "cantidad" => $cantidad
        );
    }
```

y los quiero mostrar con esto

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_SESSION["carrito"]) && !empty($_SESSION["carrito"])) {//valido que existan
    foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $actual => $valor) {//recorro el arreglo                                        
?>
<tr>
   <th><?php echo $valor["id"] //muestro?></th>  
</tr>
<?php 
  } } //fin if y forheach
?>
```

No se que paso me mostro los datos una vez y ya no mas despues sale este error

FATAL ERROR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: OBJECT OF CLASS __PHP_INCOMPLETE_CLASS COULD NOT BE CONVERTED TO STRING IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\TUTRAGO\PRESENTACION\CARRO\CARRITOCOMPRA.PHP:67 STACK TRACE: #0 C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\TUTRAGO\INDEX.PHP(49): INCLUDE() #1 {MAIN} THROWN IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\TUTRAGO\PRESENTACION\CARRO\CARRITOCOMPRA.PHP ON LINE 67

no se como solucionarlo por eso les pido ayuda se los agredaseria muco

Comment: Has un `var_dump()` a `$_SESSION["carrito"]` y agrega a tu pregunta que salida tienes

Comment: hola, en la funcion sí, podrias ser mas especifico por favor y la salida que obtengo es el error de abajo agradezco su ayuda

Comment: hola, en la funcion sí, podrias ser mas especifico por favor y la salida que obtengo es el error de abajo agradezco su ayuda

Comment: El error es por qué con echo estás tratando de imprimir algo distinto a un string un array por ejemplo, por eso te pido lo del primer comentario

Comment: ok lo hice asi `<th><?php print var_dump($valor["id"]);?></th>` esto es una parte de la salida

Comment: ARRAY(1) { [0]=> OBJECT(__PHP_INCOMPLETE_CLASS)#1 (10) { ["__PHP_INCOMPLETE_CLASS_NAME"]=> STRING(5) "LICOR" ["IDLICORES":"LICOR":PRIVATE]=> STRING(1) "1" ["NOMBRE":"LICOR":PRIVATE]=> STRING(5) "REDDS"

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos la llamada que haces a la funcion agregarLicor y podrías hacer un var_dump de los parametros que le pasas a dicha función?

Comment: puede que el error solo sea de sintaxis? probaste corregir esta linea `<th><?php echo $valor["id"] //muestro?></th>` y que quede `<th><?php echo $valor["id"]; ?></th>`

Comment: si eso solo es para mostrarles que era lo que hacia pero como lo muestra lo tenia y me mostro los datos una vez luego no los volvió a mostrar y no entiendo como sucedió

Comment: como todo va con el MVC lo separo por carpetas